# Count number of + and - values based on another column

Tags: sql, countif, dimension

I am trying to get a simple count of all the negative and positive values of a specific column on my database. I want to be able to count these values based on another column. What would be the best way to go about handling this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/terrb.png)

Comment: Please edit the question and provide more details - table definition with sample data, expected output, and tag with database platform.  Thanks,

Comment: I have updated a snip of my problem. Thanks.

Comment: *I want to be able to count these values based on another column* can you explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN column > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_positive,
  SUM(CASE WHEN column < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_negative
FROM
  table
```

You must put the column name, table name, and decide whether 0 is positive, negative or excluded (my choice)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added an image link for a clearer picture. In this case, if I ran a query I should be able to output: Positive = 3 /////////  Negative = 6

Comment: Replace `column` with your column name (funding?) and `table` with your table name (no idea what it's called)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was just stating that your answer is correct one!